# PowerShell and WMI to modify BIOS settings

Tags: powershell

I am trying to set the BIOS power-on password for HP  using PowerShell /WMI. By going through the HP Client Management Interface technical white paper from HP, which describes the class and method to accomplish this task, and research. I came to know about the following command. I have set the setup password successfully. but unable to set power-on password.

```
$Interface = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/hp/InstrumentedBIOS -Class HP_BIOSSettingInterface
$Interface.SetBIOSSetting("Power-on Password","<utf-16/>" + "pass","<utf-16/>" + "pass")
```

The command runs successfully, however, it displays the following output with the return code 1

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://developers.hp.com/hp-client-management/doc/understanding-hp-bios-settings), return code 1 indicates the setting (or value) is "Not Supported"

Comment: Suggest you use the HP Client Management Script Library instead: https://developers.hp.com/hp-client-management/doc/Bios-and-Device

Comment: @Scepticalist I have tried this too but it's showing not supported

Comment: @Skittari Perhaps the board in question doesn't support Power-on Passwords? Does it show up when you fetch all settings with `Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/hp/InstrumentedBIOS -Class HP_BIOSSetting`?

Comment: You're running this locally?  I usually use the hp bios utility over remote powershell, but I have to start it through task scheduler because of the authentication of the password.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen NO , power-on password is not showing. where i'm going wrong??please help me out

Comment: @js2010 yes I'm running this locally. can share what's the code snippet which works for you to set powwer-on password??

Comment: As I mentioned above, the feature might not be supported - if the given model is supposed to support it: contact vendor support. If not? Well, nothing you can do short of replacing the boards :)